# React using multiple Dispatchers

Tags: reactjs, flux

I have a react application, where I would like to use the "Dispatcher architecture" in multiple parts of my app, that are completely unrelated to each other.

(one is the traditional component/action/store handling, and the other are some interchangeable plugins, that can register to Dispatchers in this way decoupling it from the main app.)

Since these two parts are not related to each other, I would like to use two different dispatchers for it.

Is it possible, or since the Dispatcher is singleton, I can only use one?

Answer (score 5):

Speaking from my experience with Vanilla Flux:

**It's purposely a singleton** because you want **all your Actions to go through the same gatekeeper** that disburses the update to all the stores that need to know.

**This helps developers think about their code flow as uni-directional**. With multiple dispatchers talking to multiple stores the code flow will once again become entangled and a easy mental model would break down.

Note: I know this answer is late, but I'm sure many other newcomers will at some point have this question.